# Lógica para fazer coleção de livros e filmes usando dados externos?

Tags: api, lógica

Eu estava pensando em fazer um site que mostrasse informações de filmes e livros, para isso eu pretendo pegar dados de apis como TMDB e OpenLibrary.

Minha ideia é junta-los em coleções, por exemplo a coleção Harry Potter irá conter todos os livros e filmes originais da franquia.

O site iria atualizar automaticamente os dados em períodos pré-determinados.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia relacionar esses dados e montar as coleções, como eu posso saber quais filmes e livros pertencem a mesma franquia, tem alguma lógica que permita que esse processo possa ser automático?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: TMDB  tem uma API - https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api e a Open Library também - https://openlibrary.org/developers/api. Elas irão te ajudar nisso. Sabe o que é uma API ?

Comment: Sim, sei, minha ideia é pegar os dados dessas duas apis. O meu problema não é captura dos dados, é mais um problema de lógica mesmo. Eu queria ver se tem alguma forma de o site juntar essas coleções automaticamente. Vou editar a pergunta para que fique mais específica.

Comment: Tá bem. Na verdade nem sabia que tinha API. Mas quando alguém pergunta algo assim é a primeira coisa que vou buscar. Rsrs Eu nem vi o que essas API's oferecem.

Comment: Pela lida rápida que dei agora, acho que não tem nenhum dado específico. Mas nada que uma busca por palavra não resolva.

Comment: Meu medo é que uma busca por nome tem grandes chances de ficar incorreta, se eu pesquisar Harry Potter por exemplo, tem vários livros não oficiais com esse título.

Comment: @katerinaptrv Tudo depende doq retorna na api. Se um livro do harry retorna por exemplo uma categoria "harry", e buscando por filmes retorna uma categoria "harry", você pode relacionar diretamente, porem se não retornar nenhum dados desse tipo entre livros e filmes, terá que bolar a lógica de comparação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@katerinaptrv

Não tem o que fazer; tens que comparar os dados mesmo. E, para evitar erro, vais ter que **fazer uma IA** (não será fácil). Se for algum site que tenha **usuários, podes depender deles para manter uma relação correta** ao permitir que selecionem correspondências corretas. Com isso, pode **alimentar a IA com os dados** para que ela verifique por erros nas correspondências dos usuários.

*Exemplo*: se houver algum livro referenciando Harry Potter mas que não seja relacionado aos filmes, podes depender dos usuários. Além disso, a própria **API** de ambos os serviços **garantem acesso a comentários e outros dados**. Eles **podem alimentar a IA também** - comentários possuem muita diferenciação a dados diversos.

Jeito fácil não encontrei. Não achei nada no Google de alguma biblioteca/lib pronta para isso. Foi pesquisa superficial mas realmente não encontrei.

*Editado*: talvez seja interessante varrer a **Wikipedia** para observar relação de livros com filmes. **Não como fonte garantida mas como fonte para alimentar a IA** e deixar que ela decida.